# Neo4j: Collections containing null values can not be stored in properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a csv where I want to use multiple columns in a single property. But not all columns are filled at the same time.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/emp.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Employee {ID: row.EID, Name: row.ENAME, Language: [row.L1, row.L2 , 
row.L3]});
```

Here, some values in L1 or L2 or L3 columns are empty.

I'm getting an error:'Collections containing null values can not be stored in properties.'

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/emp.csv" AS row
UNWIND [row.L1, row.L2, row.L3] AS x
WITH row, COLLECT(x) AS langs
CREATE (:Employee {ID: row.EID, Name: row.ENAME, Language: langs});
```

The `UNWIND` clause places `L1`, `L2`, and `L3` in separate data rows; and the `COLLECT` aggregation function collects them together again, but ignoring any `NULL` values.

Comment: How can I use multiple unwind statements in a single query? Now let's say I want to combine row4 and row5 as one property, then 
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/emp.csv" AS row
    UNWIND [row.L1, row.L2, row.L3] AS x
    WITH row, COLLECT(x) AS langs
    UNWIND [row.L1, row.L2] AS y
    WITH row, COLLECT(y) AS z
    CREATE (:Employee {ID: row.EID, Name: row.ENAME, Language: 
    langs,something:z});
This isn't working. I'm not able to format the code in this comment. Sorry about that

Comment: You second `WITH` clause needs to include all the identifiers you want to pass down, so it needs to include `lang`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using distinct to it filter out null values

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/emp.csv" AS row
WITH *, distinct(row.L1 + row.L2 + row.L3) as langs 
CREATE (:Employee {ID: row.EID, Name: row.ENAME, Language: langs});
```